# Where do I need to use a Synchronized statement when using a FileBackupHelper

Tags: java, android, android-file, android-backup-service

Android's [Data Backup guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#Files) says that reading and writing to internal storage is "not threadsafe" and therefore I need to use Synchronized statements when accessing the file. I've worked very little with file input/output so far, but my understanding is that `Synchronized` uses a static object to make sure multiple parts of the program don't try to edit a file at the same time.

What's not clear to me is where I need to use this statement.  I use it, for example, in the `onBackup` and `onRestore` methods as instructed in the guide:

```
public void onBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor oldState, BackupDataOutput data,
     ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
        synchronized (DBAdapter.dbBackupLockObject) {
                super.onBackup(oldState, data, newState);
        }
}
```

My question is, do I need to do the same thing everywhere I read/write the db in my code? My instinct says yes, but I want to confirm before I go adding this statement to the million places I access my db.

So should I change a snippet like this

```
db.open();
Semester curSemester = db.getSemester(curSemesterId);
db.close();
```

to

```
synchronized (DBAdapter.dbBackupLockObject) {
        db.open();
        Semester curSemester = db.getSemester(curSemesterId);
        db.close();
}
```

? Is that what I should be doing? Surround every open/close with a synchronized statement?